# NetSuite Advanced PDF Page Break

Tags: netsuite, freemarker

Looking for some support on NetSuite Advanced PDF's. I'm configuring an advanced PDF for our Purchase Orders and we're looking to add ~2 pages of terms and conditions as an appendix to our PO form within the same PDF file.

Any recommendations on how to configure this?

Answer (score 0):

Insert a `<pbr />` element prior to your T&C

If you are not using source view on the template you should start doing that. It opens a world of possibility.

You can also use `<pbr />` to change  some characteristics of the following page. See https://bfo.com/products/report/docs/userguide.pdf for details.